# What should I know if I am to watch Fafner Exodus without watching the prequel series and movie?

Tags: fafner-exodus

I watched the two first episodes of Fafner Exodus, but it was very confusing, as the story is ongoing. Not much intro.

There were a prequel series, and a movie. What should I know from this prequel material in order to understand Fafner Exodus?

Answer (score 1):

There was a prequel series, an OVA and a movie, and they do all need to be watched (and in that order) to understand Exodus.

Fafner's plot is pretty complicated. You may even need to watch the original series twice to understand it (the first half was done by a different writer and isn't as good, but makes more sense on a second watch).

It's a good series (and Exodus is brilliant so far), but it does require a fair bit of time investment, and the plot isn't for everyone.

Comment: This really does not add anything towards answering the question. "Without watching" is the keyword you are missing.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but basically my answer is the plot is too complex and the show relies on long term character development too much to be able to understand what's going on without watching the original series.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the prequel if only:

1. You want to see a first generation fight Festum.
2. You want to know why Mark Sein & Mark Nicht are so unique; after all, Mark Sein was born from Mark Nicht.
3. You want know the identity of Miwa's father.

If you think these things are not important you don't have to watch it.